# DbContext Mocking ChangeTracker with xUnit - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unit-testing, xunit

I am currently trying to track changes done to the entities. The application is an ASP.NET MVC app using Entity Framework. Within the repository I use a basic command for saving

```
DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
```

However, before that I would like to check what have changed in the entity and thus I use

```
DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>();
```

All works fine when I am running the solution, but starting up the xUnit unit tests returns an error

> System.InvalidOperationException : No connection string named "XXXX" could be found in the application config file

It seems like the mocking that I do doesn't mock the `ChangeTracker` - how can I achieve it so that I can mock the change tracker? Is there maybe other option how to prevent such a problem? How do you normally mock the `DbContext` so that it covers the change tracker as well?

Example of the code:

```
        public virtual async Task UpdateAsync(params TEntity[] items)
    {

        foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i != null).ToList())
        {
            if (item.Id == 0)
            {
                throw new CustomException(CustomExceptionReason.CannotUpdateNotCreated, item.Id.ToString());
            }

            DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            var otherCHanges = DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>();

            UpdateModifiedDate(item);

        }

        await this.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            CacheRemove(item);
        }
    }
```

Example of mocking:

```
var users = new[] { new User {Id = 1, UserName = "TestUserName", FirstName = "Test", LastName = "User"} }; 

var dbContextMock = new DbContextMock<MyEntities>();
dbContextMock.CreateDbSetMock(x => x.Users, (e, c) => e.Id, users);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you work for the EF Core team, why do you want to mock the change tracker? In fact, why create a mock DbContext instead of using eg the in-memory provider?

Comment: I am not sure what I need to mock or do, but with the current setup I get the error mentioned above "No connection string named "XXXX" could be found in the application config file". So I just thought that it might be due to missing mocking or maybe something else that I do wrong

Comment: The error has nothing to do with change tracking. You didn't post the code for `DbContextMock` but it seems it's trying to load and use a connection string. Perhaps it uses the constructor that accepts a connection string name? Instead of hard-coding the connection string (or its name) use only the constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions parameter and use `AddDbContext` to register the context and specify the connection name (or string). In a test, you can create the DbContextOptions object directly

Comment: Thanks for the answer - The DbContextMock is provided by a library "EntityFrameworkMock.Moq" so I don't have any exact details about that method.

Comment: Neither do we. That's not an EF class. What is *your* DbContext? `Entities`? It's quite likely the mock DbContext is calling your own class's constructor. You'll be able to use your own DbContext class if you remove the hard-coded connection string name and use DbContextOptions